# cpuminer (version 2.4.5 win32) error "json-rpc call failed:[-1,"'L' format requires 0 <=number<= 4294967295",null]" how to solve it?

Tags: python, bitcoin

cpuminer (version 2.4.5 win32) error "json-rpc call failed:[-1,"'L'  format requires 0 <=number<= 4294967295",null]" how to solve it ?

other parameters are "--scrypt -o stratum+tcp://global.wemineltc.com:3333"

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow, please have a look how to post a question (here)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]

Answer (score -3):

had this same problem when I was trying initially using minerd with stratum+tcp://wemineltc.com:3333

changed to litcoinpool.org and the problem was solved.